Using FLTK with CMake, undefined references
Been struggling with this for a while, im trying to get FLTK working with CLion using CMake (been getting undefined references errors), I've tried all of the formats suggested online and in the readme:
CMakelist (different approaches I've tried):
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.30)
project(exercises)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(FLTK_DIR C:/fltk)

FIND_PACKAGE(FLTK REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

include_directories(${FLTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${FLTK_LIBRARIES})
add_definitions(${FLTK_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(exercises main.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(exercises fltk)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.30)
project(exercises)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(FLTK_DIR C:/fltk)

find_package(FLTK 1.4 CONFIG REQUIRED)


add_executable(exercises main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(exercises PRIVATE fltk::fltk)
target_compile_features(exercises PUBLIC cxx_std_20)

Main.cpp
#include <FL/FL.h>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
int main() {
    Fl_Window win(100, 100, "ciao");
    return 0;
}

Error:
undefined reference to `Fl_Window::Fl_Window(int, int, char const*)'
undefined reference to `Fl_Window::~Fl_Window()'

I've installed FLTK in a folder in C (path C:/fltk) using CMake (default configs) and compiled it with VS 17, all the libs formed correctly in fltk/lib/debug from what I can see.
Sorry if it's a simple question but I'm a beginner in using C++ dependancies and I'm just starting out with CMake

Am I correctly understand you, that either variant of CMakeLists.txt you show gives the same error messages, shown in your post?

Just a guess, but I see "FIND_PACKAGE(FLTK ..." and then "TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(exercises fltk)" and my first thought is "hmm, FLTK and fltk is not the same thing"..

Are you using visual studio to compile your application?

To address the comments yes either variants result in the same error, fltk should be good to find the package according to documentation and yeah im using CMake to generate the visual studio solution and then compiling it.

The 2nd version of your CMakeLists.txt file works fine with FLTK 1.4.1: I tested it successfully with CMake 3.29 after reducing cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29) to 3.29.
How exactly did you install FLTK in C:/fltk? The correct way to do it with VS (I'm using VS 2019) is to right-click on the "INSTALL" target in the project explorer and select "build". Yes, this looks weird, but this is what CMake + VS need. After that I found all the libs in C:/fltk/lib as you wrote.
There should also be 5 files (*.cmake) in C:/fltk/CMake/. Do these files also exist? If not you didn't install FLTK correctly. Go back and do it as I described. If you did, continue...
Now the next step is to build your project with CMake. I assume that you have your main.cpp file and CMakeLists.txt in the same folder. Open CMake and select the source folder (where these files live) and the binary folder (e.g. the folder build inside the source folder). Then click on "Configure". If you did this you should have seen an error message. Note for the future: please post error messages if you ask questions (use copy/paste). What I see is an error message and some instructions:
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "FLTK"
  (requested version 1.4) with any of the following names:

    FLTKConfig.cmake
    fltk-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "FLTK" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "FLTK_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "FLTK"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

The first file FLTKConfig.cmake is one of the 5 files in C:/fltk/CMake/. As the instructions say: you have two choices. You need to define one of two CMake variables by clicking on the '+' button ("Add Entry"):

add FLTK_DIR with value C:/fltk/CMake/ or
add CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH with value C:/fltk.

I did the latter and VS found FLTK and built the project successfully. Finally I modified your main.cpp so it shows the window and waits until the window is closed:
#include <FL/Fl.H>    // note: typo fixed
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
int main() {
    Fl_Window win(100, 100, "ciao");
    win.show();
    return Fl::run();
}

That's it. Let us know if this works, or post what you did and related error messages.
PS: there are other ways to specify the required variables but that would be OT here.

Note: there were two typos in the first include statement but they are harmless on Windows since the filesystem is case insensitive. The first statement should read: #include <FL/Fl.H>. Without this correction your program wouldn't build on Linux or other platforms with case sensitive filesystems.

PPS: another way to define FLTK_DIR correctly would be in your CMakeLists.txt like this: set(FLTK_DIR "C:/fltk/CMake" CACHE PATH "path to FLTKConfig.cmake") as recommended in the current version of README.CMake.txt in the FLTK 1.4.1 sources. Note the CACHE keyword which makes it a CMake cache variable that can be viewed by the CMake GUI.

tried doing everything as stated in your response. I even installed FLTK directly on the disk so i didn't even have to set FLTK_DIR, the problem still persists, the compiler isn't linking the libraries and so the same error message from before (in my post) of undefined references keeps appearing

You must either define FLTK_DIR or CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to match what I wrote above. The former points at the directory where the 5 mentioned .cmake files are, the latter should point at the folder where you installed FLTK. I don't understand "I even installed FLTK directly on the disk" (why did you do this?), and why do you think you "didn't even have to set FLTK_DIR" ? Without further info what exactly you did (not words like "everything as stated in your response") and exact error messages I'm afraid we can't help you. As I wrote above I tested your project and it worked for me as expected.

Hint: Please ask FLTK user questions on FLTK's official support channels, either on fltk.general (Google Groups, https://groups.google.com/g/fltkgeneral) or on GitHub Discussions (Q&A): https://github.com/fltk/fltk/discussions/categories/q-a which FLTK developers and other users monitor frequently. And don't forget to post your commands and real error messages.
Although stackoverflow can be helpful it's not an official support channel of FLTK.

PS: are you sure you really installed FLTK 1.4.0 or 1.4.1? The instructions posted by me above don't work with FLTK 1.3.x ! If you want to use 1.3.x then you need to use a different CMakeLists.txt file!
Note that I wrote explicitly: "The 2nd version of your CMakeLists.txt file works fine with FLTK 1.4.1".
